# Centos 6.8 enable curl extension for php on php.ini

Tags: php, curl, centos

in my server i have `Centos-6.8-64bit` with `php5.6`

on this server which i have WHM `curl` is installed on that

```
[root@s5 ~]# curl -V
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
[root@s5 ~]#
```

and when in try to use `curl` i get this error:

```
cURL error 56: Received HTTP code 405 from proxy after CONNECT (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).
```

in WHM and selecting `MultiPHP INI Editor` i have only this lines for curl

php version:`ep-php56`

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
;curl.cainfo =
```

how can i resolve this problem to use curl extension for php?

Comment: 405 is an error status from the remote server which show that curl installation worked. Could you better describe what your problem is? From the question alone curl looks working, so not an issue with the curl extension on centos you ask about.

Comment: @hakre i'm trying to use curl on php, i think curl extension is not enable for php on php.ini, how can i check that?

Comment: if you can call the curl function - which you demonstrated you could - it is enabled. That you get an error message is not proving the opposite, ineed the curl error shows curl is working and it can normally report HTTP errors to you. In case it would not be enabled you would see a fatal error about an undefined function instead. You're most likely just wide-circle around between the outer circle not having curl enabled at any case w/o further approval of the extensions enablement status and just calling the method and seeing an unepected error from a remote HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Best thing you could do IMHO is to double check with the documentation of the WHM you're using on how to enable PHP extensions which should contain a part that allows you to check if the configuration action was successful or not. If the software you're using does not provide such documentation properties please consult your system administrator.